# I want to parse the data obtained by using CURL to get useful information from the result

Tags: php, curl, html-parsing

As guided i am reposting the question in full detail. The aim of code is to retrieve the result from remote server and store it to my database and then display it when required by user from my server's database.

i want to retrieve individual sbject and marks  from the site.

```
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('rid' => '1kn06cs032','submit' =>   'SUBMIT'));

if(!($result = curl_exec($request)))
    die('curl_exec failed with error: '.curl_error($request));

curl_close($request);

//echo strip_tags($result,'<tr><b><td>') ;
  $s=strip_tags($result,'') ;
//strstr($s,")");
  $t=strstr($s,"(PROVISIONAL)");
   echo $t;
   //$a=explode('Semester:',$t);
   //echo $a[0];
   //echo $a[1];

 ?>
```

Please guide me in this regard i have struck in this as i have tried many alternative bt no luck as i have little knowledge of parsing and basic knowledge of php .

Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to parse the data obtained by using curl to get useful information from the result   ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585360/i-want-to-parse-the-data-obtained-by-using-curl-to-get-useful-information-from-th), you should edit your existing question instead create another question

Answer (score 0):

This still isn't really enough information. The output that you get back from this `Curl` call would be useful.

It may be worth looking into PHP's [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DomXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) this will allow you to query HTML and XML using Xpath's query language

For example :

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile(HTML_FROM_CURL_HERE);
$xpath = new DOMXpath();

// Get all divs
$divs = $xpath->query("//div");

// Get the div with the id of 'container' which is direct child of the body element
$container = $xpath->query("/body/div[id='container']");
```

I hope that gets you started.

Jake

Answer (score 0):

```
use this method to parse the data 

$result = curl_exec($request);  

$json_a1=json_decode($result,true);
$json_o1=json_decode($result);

foreach($json_o1->data as $p1)
{
    echo $p1->id;
}
```